# Jersey 2.x post call with json input paramater throws MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException

Tags: java, json, jersey, jersey-2.0

I try to map directly from and to json. For the GET requests this is working smoothly. For the POST requests an exception occurs.

resource methods:

```
@GET
@Path("testget")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response test(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    Password password = new Password();
    password.setPassword("testpassword");
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(password).build();
}

@POST
@Path("testpost")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response test(Password password) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(password.getPassword()).build();
}
```

client:

```
    Response reponse = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

    Password password = new Password();
    password.setPassword("newTestPasswort");
    reponse = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(password));
```

exception:

```
    SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json,        type=class com.entities.Password, genericType=class      com.entities.Password.
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.entities.Password, genericType=class com.entities.Password.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:502)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
    at com.clientsql.RegistrationTest.setNewPassword(RegistrationTest.java:61)
    at com.clientsql.RegistrationTest.main(RegistrationTest.java:44)
```

dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

For the mapping i tried a variety of dependencies. For each only the get function works:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
 </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>-->
```

Comment: You need to register a provider for the client to do the mapping to/from json, there is an example using Genson [here](http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/Extensions/#jax-rs-jersey--cie).

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell jersey how to convert an object to/from JSON.

There are multiple approaches to support JSON in jersey.

Take a look to official Jersey documentation for different approaches to support JSON : https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e7963

Below two are common way to do this :

1. JAXB based JSON binding support

   Add `@XmlRootElement` annotation for POJOs.

   ```
   @XmlRootElement
   class EntityX {
       // data
   }
   ```
2. POJO based JSON binding support

   You need to register a provider which implements ContextResolver. Using Jackson you can do this.

   ```
   @Provider
   @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
   public class JacksonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

       private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

       public JacksonContextResolver() throws Exception {
           this.objectMapper = buildMapper(false);
       }

       public static ObjectMapper buildMapper(boolean indent) {
           ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
           objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH));
           AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
           AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
           AnnotationIntrospector pair = new AnnotationIntrospector.Pair(primary, secondary);

           SerializationConfig sc = objectMapper.getSerializationConfig()
               .withAnnotationIntrospector(pair)
               .withSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
           objectMapper.setSerializationConfig(sc);

           if (indent) {
               objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
           }

           return objectMapper;
       }

       /**
        * @see javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver#getContext(java.lang.Class)
        */
       public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
           return objectMapper;
       }
   }
   ```

   Check this link for more information : https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson